# Qt/QML: How do I "switch to" or "open" another QML file without restarting my app?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qqmlapplicationengine

I have a little application that loads a QML file from a server and displays some kind of "book shelf" to the user.

The user can pick one of the displayed books and C++ will download a ZIP file in the background, unpacks it. The result is a folder for each book on the file system with a "main.qml" file which is basically a self-contained version of the book, allowing the user to browse/zoom/etc.

I'm using `ApplicationWindow` to display the book shelf in its QML file, and now I'm wondering what would be the *best* approach to "switch" to the book and display it in the ApplicationWindow. By *best* I mean, it would be nice if the book shelf is pretty much "unloaded" from memory to free resources for the book display.

How would I do this?

My rough ideas, which don't feel quite "right" were:

- Use `QQmlApplicationEngine::load()` to load another URL?
- Add the book's QML component as a topmost child object to the shelf; but this would result in lots of wasted resources.
- ...?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You can manually create/destroy QML components from within QML's Javascript context: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution would be to just use a `Loader` in your application window. Set it use your `main.qml` on instantiation, and then when the user selects a book, set the `Loader`'s source to the book's QML file.

However it would better to load the 'screens' dynamically, then you could use transitioning effects before destroying the previous screen.